# How to scale font when the font-face is having only one font-size using MFC's DrawText

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, fonts

.
    void CMainWindow::OnPaint()
    {
        CPaintDC DC(this);
        //CRect rc(5, 5, 191, 99);
        CRect rc(1, 1, 38, 19);

```
    CBrush brush(DC.GetBkColor());  
    CBrush* pOldBrush = DC.SelectObject(&brush); 
    DC.FillRect(&rc, &brush);
    DC.SelectObject(pOldBrush);

    DC.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);

    LOGFONT LogFont;
    LogFont.lfHeight        = -13;
    LogFont.lfWidth         = 0;
    LogFont.lfEscapement        = 0;
    LogFont.lfOrientation       = 0;
    LogFont.lfWeight        = 400;
    LogFont.lfItalic        = 0;
    LogFont.lfUnderline     = 0;
    LogFont.lfStrikeOut     = 0;
    LogFont.lfCharSet       = 0;
    LogFont.lfOutPrecision      = 0;
    LogFont.lfClipPrecision     = 0;
    LogFont.lfQuality       = 0;
    LogFont.lfPitchAndFamily    = 0;
    wcscpy_s(LogFont.lfFaceName,    _T("System"));

    //float OffSetY = 1.0;
    //float OffSetX = 1.0;

    float OffSetY = 0.2;
    float OffSetX = 0.2;
    LogFont.lfHeight        = (int)(LogFont.lfHeight * OffSetY); 
    LogFont.lfWidth         = (int)(LogFont.lfWidth * OffSetX); 

    CFont* pFont = new CFont;
    pFont->CreateFontIndirect(&LogFont); 

    CFont* pOldFont = DC.SelectObject( pFont );

    CString sTemp(_T("Title  current_folder\r\nField1\r\nComment:\r\nControl #:\r\nDescription:\r\nMagnification:\r\n"));
    sTemp.Replace(_T("&"), _T("&&"));

    int alignment = 0;
    switch(alignment)
    {
    case 1:
        DC.DrawText(sTemp, -1, rc, DT_WORDBREAK | DT_RIGHT | DT_EDITCONTROL);
        break;

    case 2:                                                       
        DC.DrawText(sTemp, -1, rc, DT_WORDBREAK | DT_CENTER | DT_EDITCONTROL);
        break;

    default:
        DC.DrawText(sTemp, -1, rc, DT_WORDBREAK | DT_EDITCONTROL);
        break;   
    }

    DC.SelectObject( pOldFont );

    delete pFont;
}
```

[image: output at all the cases mentioned]

When using System or FixedSys font (which have only one font size 10 and 9 resp) then in the text drawn is perfect in case when OffSetX and OffSetY is 1 and rc(5, 5, 191, 99). But If I change the OffSetX and OffSetY to 0.2 and rc(1, 1, 38, 19) then the text if truncated from bottom-right. This is case only when using the mentioned font which is having just one font-size and for other font is working fine and text drawn is properly scaled.

Since the font is having one font-size so `DrawText` is using this font size in all cases and rect given is too small to accommodate this text so it is showing only the few characters.
Is there any way I can fixed it, so that the text get scaled at these zoom conditions. This is the behavior I am getting in one of MFC Project when I perform zoom-in operation at the scenario mentioned above.

Any suggestion or alternative for this will be very helpful and appreciable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hard-code your font size like that! Instead, perform necessary calculations:

```
const int SIZE_IN_POINTS = 12;
LogFont.lfHeight = -MulDiv(SIZE_IN_POINTS, DC.GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSY), 72);
```

Comment: Yes off course! I get this value using this too. But just for explaining my scenario here. I used those constant.

Comment: I think the problem is because fixed size font are bitmap and not scalable as of true-type font which is scalable

Comment: Try the `System` font in Wordpad. Works. Did you try to perform your zoom multiplication on the `SIZE_IN_POINTS` value instead of the final `lfHeight` value?